# TensorFlow on Python 3.6 - how to avoid session creation overhead

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I'm running a simple beheaded DCNN (Incepton-V3 w ImageNet weights) on TF, and moving from TF 1.0.1 / PY 35 to TF 1.9 / PY 36 (both using Anaconda on Windows7), I've found my runtimes went up by near 2x (with nearly same code).

A bit more details -

In older environment (Py3.5 TF1.0.1), I used on open session, like:

```
def image_extract_features(sess, allTensors, imgfilename):
    imgdata = read_file(imgfilename)
    imgResized = sess.run(readTensor, {dataTensor: imgdata})
    imgEmbed = sess.run(bottlenecktensor, {resizedTensor: imgResized})
    return imgEmbed

sess, graph, allTensors, modelInfo = initiate_graph(modelDir)
for _ in range(100):
    imgfilename = browseFileName()
    if not imgfilename:
        break
    feats = image_extract_features(sess, allTensors, imgfilename)
```

When I ran that on new environment (Py3.6/TF), I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

So instead I tried

```
def image_extract_features(graph, allTensors, imgfilename):
    ...
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        imgResized = sess.run(readTensor, {dataTensor: imgdata})
        imgEmbed = sess.run(bottlenecktensor, {resizedTensor: imgResized})
    return imgEmbed
```

This is where I got about 2x rise in runtime per image (from ~0.5 to ~1 seconds).
Also, running the same with Keras (the obvious way) resulted in ~0.9sec per image.

Goal - go back to ~0.5sec per image on my machine.

To consolidate my suspicion in the session creation, and knowing that the image decoding+resizing is relatively fast, I wrote the following loop:

```
from time import time as now
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    t = [now()]
    for imgfile in imgfiles:
        imgResized = sess.run(readTensor, {dataTensor: open(imgfile, 'rb').read()})
        t.append( now() )
    (np.diff(t)*1000).astype(int).tolist()
```

Which, on a 3-files  list, gave the following results:

```
[378,   4,  19] # Runtime per file [ms]
```

Shuffled  and reran. Got:

```
[371,  10,   5] # Runtime per file [ms]
```

So, we see that the 1st item after the session creation is way slower.

My final question is this: given my application is

- get image file
- run beheaded DCNN
- do something with the resulting features

and I can't hold the session open, what can I do to avoid this new session overhead?

Thank you

Comment: Please tell me if I can be clearer or be as clear using half the characters.

Comment: As far as my experience goes, on Windows 1) importing TensorFlow is slow 2) creating a session is slow 3) the first computation in a session is slower than the following ones (comparing these with a Linux setup, where there are also sources of overhead but they all seem smaller). Which is pretty much what you are describing, and unfortunately I don't think there is any way around it. I have similar overhead on a C++ application where TensorFlow is used as a DLL, so it's deeper than Python level. The only solution is to somehow keep a session permanently alive.

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa , knowing it's deper than the Py level is important. Also knowing in Linux it's better. Do you know a way to keep the sess alive (other than go back 9 versions)?

Comment: I posted an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some change has caused `initiate_graph` to return an invalid session for some reason. If you do not want to or cannot investigate or fix that, you can just ignore it and make your own session, keeping the same original code structure.

```
def image_extract_features(sess, allTensors, imgfilename):
    imgdata = read_file(imgfilename)
    imgResized = sess.run(readTensor, {dataTensor: imgdata})
    imgEmbed = sess.run(bottlenecktensor, {resizedTensor: imgResized})
    return imgEmbed

_, graph, allTensors, modelInfo = initiate_graph(modelDir)
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    for _ in range(100):
        imgfilename = browseFileName()
        if not imgfilename:
            break
        feats = image_extract_features(sess, allTensors, imgfilename)
```

Also, you can always create a session and store it in a variable (e.g. `sess = tf.Session()`, instead of using it in a `with` block), then use it as many times as you need. You just have to make sure it is closed when it is not needed anymore (e.g. with a `try`/`finally` block).

Comment: Yep, I did exactly that, which is what doubled my runtime per image. I'll update the qu with a snip from `initiate_graph`, hopefully you'll (or someone else) have something to say about it

Comment: @Ori5678 Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but I thought what doubled the runtime was creating a new session on each call to `image_extract_features`.

Comment: I did exactly that -  "instead of using it in a `with` block"...
added explicit "sess = tf.Session()" and it worked. The returned session is alive and the execution is fast! Thanks!

Comment: And now a chained question - Is possible to manipulate Keras to do the same? But maybe I'll open a new question for that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ori5678 Feel free to ask another question if you want, but I think Keras uses one permanent session you can get from the backend with `get_session` (see `get_session` in [`tensorflow_backend.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py), it's not in the documentation because it's TensorFlow-specific but is is used in some examples). You can also reset it with `clear_session` and set it with `set_session`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747081/keras-is-slower-than-tensorflow-on-the-same-task     @jdehsa