# Keras is slower than TensorFlow on the same task

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Python to run a beheaded DCNN (Inception-V3 in this case) to get image features. I'm using Anaconda, Py3.6 and Windows7.

When using TensorFlow, I keep the session in a variable (thanks jdehesa) and run:

```
sess, graph, allTensors, modelInfo = initiate_graph(modelDir)
while True:
    filename = getImageFile()
    if not filename: break
    imgResized = fileReadAndResize(filename)
    feats = np.squeeze( sess.run(allTensors['dcnn'], {allTensors['resizedInput']: imgResized}) )  
    doSmthWithFeats(feats)
```

When running it like this (where `allTensors['dcnn']` runs Inception-V3 without its last layer), I get that `sess.run(...)` takes ~0.4 seconds.

I wanted to move to Keras because of it's simplicity and easy of running and comparing multiple standard DCNNs.

My Keras parallel is:

```
def createModel():
    model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=Input(shape=(299, 299, 3)), include_top=False)
    x = model.output
    x = AveragePooling2D((8, 8), strides=(8, 8))(x)
    return Model(model.input, x)

modelIncptV3 = createModel()
while True:
    ...
    feats = model.predict(np.expand_dims(imgResized, 0)).flatten()
    doSmthWithFeats(feats)
```

Now, here the `feats` creation line takes ~1.1 seconds (while producing the same features).

I tried to compile model first

```
model.compile( optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True) )
```

runtime per image is now about 1.0 second.

I've had a similar problem with different codes in TF, there my difference in runtime was due to initiating a session for each image. Is this alike? Anything I can do to preserve the session? Any other ideas to make performance on par with plain TF?

Thank you